# julia 1.0 installation tests - nix-pkgs - ubuntu

Tags: julia, ubuntu-16.04, nixpkgs

My laptop:

> Linux g-TP 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44
>   UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I installed julia via nix-env and got the following test result

```
Test Summary: |     Pass  Broken     Total
  Overall     | 37420635  327815  37748450
    SUCCESS
```

What can / should I do for resolving the 327815 broken tests?

Comment: It's recommended that you use the [generic binaries downloaded from the Julia website](https://julialang.org/). The reason is because Julia uses a patched version of LLVM6 to fix bugs (not all of the patches have been upstreamed), and many package managers use a system LLVM without the patches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test that is marked as broken (with `@test_broke`) does not lead to a test failure, all tests passed as indicated by the `SUCCESS` in the output.

From the docs of `@test_broken`:

```
help?> @test_broken
  @test_broken ex

  Indicates a test that should pass but currently consistently fails.
  Tests that the expression ex evaluates to false or causes an exception.
  Returns a Broken Result if it does, or an Error Result if the expression evaluates to true.
```

Example:

```
julia> using Test

julia> @testset begin
           @test 1 == 1 # results in a Pass
           @test 1 == 2 # results in a Fail
           @test_broken 1 == 2 # results in a Broken
       end

Test Summary: | Pass  Fail  Broken  Total
test set      |    1     1       1      3
ERROR: Some tests did not pass: 1 passed, 1 failed, 0 errored, 1 broken.
```

Comment: With a second execution I get : ERROR: `LoadError: Some tests did not pass: 1 passed, 1 failed, 0 errored, 1 broken.
in expression starting at /home/user/Julia/test_Julia.jl:3` followed by finish(::Test.DefaultTestSet) at Test.jl:847
top-level scope at Test.jl:1088
include_string(::Module, ::String, ::String) at loading.jl:1002
(::getfield(Atom, Symbol("##120#125")){String,String,Module})() at eval.jl:120
withpath(::getfield(Atom, Symbol("##120#125")){String,String,Module}, ::String) at utils.jl:30
withpath at eval.jl:46 [inlined]
#119 at eval.jl:117 [inlined]
hideprompt(::getfield(Ato